# Simulate special key presses keyup events

Tags: c#

I'm using the [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) function and I'm having an issue with simulating certain keys. At the moment, the issue is namely the `CONTROL` button.

Here's some of my code for simulating the key down and key up events:

```
switch (record.keyMsg)
{
    //Key down event
    case "WM_KEYDOWN":
        keybd_event((byte)record.keyCode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
        Debug.WriteLine("Key down.");
        break;
    //Key up event
    case "WM_KEYUP":
        keybd_event((byte)record.keyCode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        Debug.WriteLine("Key up.");
        break;
}
```

Now, when the program simulates the `CONTROL` button, it seems that the button gets "stuck". I visited this site: http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events to see exactly what kind of events were actually being fired.

When I normally press the `CONTROL` button in the event watcher on that site, here's the output:

```
keydown    keyCode=17    which=17    charCode=0    char= +ctrl
keyup      keyCode=17    which=17    charCode=0    char=
```

But when my code simulates the `CONTROL` button, here's the output:

```
keydown    keyCode=17    which=17    charCode=0    char= +ctrl
keyup      keyCode=17    which=17    charCode=0    char= +ctrl
```

Furthermore, the same sort of problem happens with the `SHIFT` key. Using the same site mentioned before, when I manually type the `SHIFT` key, here's the output:

```
keydown    keyCode=16    which=16    charCode=0    char= +shift
keyup      keyCode=16    which=16    charCode=0    char=
```

Yet, when the program simulates this, here's the output:

```
keydown    keyCode=16    which=16    charCode=0    char= +shift
```

It isn't even doing the `keyup` event at this point.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I believe the culprit of the key being "stuck" is that `keyup` event, but I have no clue how I'm supposed to fix that. Anyone have any tips or clues?

EDIT: To elaborate on what I meant by "stuck: When the code simulates the `CONTROL` button, and then I try to type things into notepad, the computer believes that the `CONTROL` key is still being pressed. When I type `s`, it prompts to save in notepad, etc.. To fix this, I just press both left ctrl and right ctrl to fix this.